# Can a walk in a graph be empty?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph. A walk is a sequence of vertices in $G$, where every pair of consecutive vertices are adjacent. Do we allow the empty sequence as a walk?

Comment: I like to know where I'm starting and finishing, even if I know I'm not going anywhere.

Comment: @user107952: No, we do not allow an empty sequence as a walk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be empty in the sense of no edges (start on a vertex, don't traverse any edges, end on same vertex).  But it does have to have a starting and an ending vertex (which could be the same, with or without intermediate edges).

Comment: I wonder if there is a relative walk as well as said absolute version, this then could be genuinely empty.